# How to remove every other line with sed?

Tags: sed

How can I remove every odd line, using sed?

```
remove
keep
remove
keep
remove
...
```

Comment: Half of the questions this morning seem to be april fools jokes as well...

Comment: If it's April Fool's, then the answer must be: grep Not input.txt

Comment: @paxdiablo: But what about `grep -v Remove`?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

GNU sed has a suitable addressing mode:

```
sed -n '1~2!p' file
```

which means, starting from line 1, and with step 2, print all other lines.

Equivalently, you can drop the `-n`, and delete matching lines:

```
sed '1~2d'
```

It can also be done using awk:

```
awk 'NR%2==0' file
```

(Whenever line number is a multiple of 2, print the line)

Comment: Thank you for this! very helpful.

Comment: I get the error "invalid command code ~" when I try this with sed on macos.

Comment: Note that line 1, in this case, means line 2 because apparently line numbers for `sed` start at 0. So if you want to print odd lines, you would use `sed -n '0~2!p' file`

Comment: @alejandro Line numbers for sed start at 1. What isn't explained in this answer is that the exclamation point negates the sense of the preceding address specification. https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html#tag_20_116_13_03 https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Addresses-overview.html

Comment: Without exclamation points: _Print odd lines:_ `sed -n '1~2p' file`   , _Print even lines:_  `sed -n '0~2p' file`.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification @RobinA.Meade! I see what you mean, and I think the answer would be more clear without the exclamation points, as you have posted. My only adjustment would be to use `sed -n '2~2p' file` to print even lines

Comment: @alejandro It _does_ feel strange to specify the starting line as `0` when line `0` doesn't actually exist, but the GNU sed documentation shows exactly that: "one would use 1~2 to select the odd-numbered lines and 0~2 for even-numbered lines" https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Numeric-Addresses.html#Numeric-Addresses

Comment: @AlexSpurling For those of you getting the "invalid command code" error, it is probably because you are using double quotes (`"`) instead of single quotes (`'`) as showed in the answer

Answer (score 36):

Here is the shortest I can think of:

```
sed -n 'g;n;p' file
```

It should work with non-GNU versions of `sed` (as well as GNU `sed`).

Comment: This works on OS X too! (Unlike `sed -n '1~2!p'`.) It takes lines 2,4,6,... I couldn't figure out from the man page how to take lines 1,3,5,... Adding a first line is a simple hack, though.

Comment: @Nagel: Try: `sed -n 'p;n' file` or `sed 'n;d' file` for outputting the odd lines. By the way, I don't think the `g` is necessary for outputting the even lines: `sed -n 'n;p' file` seems to work.

Answer (score 13):

This works with GNU and BSD (mac) versions of sed:

**To remove odd lines** (print even rows):

```
sed -n ’n;p’ file
```

Might look a bit confusing, so here is what happens under the hood step by step:

1. sed: reads in first line
2. -n: suppress output of first line
3. n: output is suppressed, so don’t write anything out
4. n (again): read next (second) line to pattern buffer, i.e. to process immediately
5. p: print anything available in the pattern buffer overriding suppressed output, i.e. the 2nd line
6. sed: reads in third line, since second line got already processed thanks to “n” in step4
7. -n: suppress output of third line
8. ...
9. ...

**To remove even lines** (print odd rows):

```
sed -n ‘p;n’ file
```

Here is what happens under the hood algorithmically:

1. sed: reads in first line
2. -n: suppress output of first line
3. p: prints content of pattern buffer, i.e. the first line, overriding suppressed output
4. n: output is suppressed, so don’t write anything out
5. n (again): read in next (second) line to pattern buffer for immediate processing, but since there are no more commands, nothing happens
6. sed: reads in third line, since second line got already “processed” thanks to “n” in step5
7. -n: suppress output of third line
8. p: prints third line overriding suppressed output
9. ...

Comment: This should be the accepted answer because not only does it work everywhere, the answer shows how to display both even and odd numbered lines.

Answer (score 5):

Perl solution:

```
perl -ne 'print if $. % 2 == 0' file
```

`$.` is the line number

Comment: The guy asked for `sed`, which shows poor reading skills on your part, but someone might find this useful, so +1.

Comment: I answered since sed, awk, and perl can often be used interchangeably.
While there are differences in speed and simplicity, they are all used on the command line or inside shell scripts.

Answer (score 2):

One more awk :

```
awk getline file
```