# How to process every second file in bash?

Tags: bash, scripting, find

I have a directory with a few dozens of files. I would like to do something with every second file from this directory. By now I only used `find` command but with this I process all files:

```
find ./dir/ -type f -exec cat {} \;
```

Comment: is there any special pattern of name for the second file?

Comment: @ajreal: I was thinking about this. All files looks similar, but ends on `_tX.XXXXXXX` where X's are some numbers. Usualy they are in some range, for example from 0.1 to 2.0 and they grow geometricaly from smallest value to largest. And there is no specific number of files. So I can have 10 files in range from 0.1 to 2, or 100 files in the same range. I'm not sure if there is some simple pattern to match every second file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
cnt=0; 
for file in $(find ./dir -type f); <-- if not too many matches
do 
  let cnt=cnt+1; 
  if [ $cnt -eq 2 ]; 
    then echo $file;               <-- do something
    cnt=0;                         <-- alternate file
  fi; 
done
```

or

```
second_file=$(find -type f | head -2 | tail -1);
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. In first example you need to add `cnt=0` inside `if` - so it will be every second file, not only second :)

Answer (score 21):

```
for file in `find dir -type f | awk 'NR % 2 == 0'`; do
  echo $file
done
```

`NR` is the current row number. To get odd rows, use `... == 1`.

Comment: this is probably the cleanest of the methods presented. Good stuff.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run my_cmd on each of the alternate file, this may help

```
 find ./dir -type f | sort -n | sed -n '1~2!p'  | sed 's/^/mycmd  /' | sh
```

I've copied the sed from [How to remove every other line with sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2560411/how-to-remove-every-other-line)

Answer (score 0):

I had every file twice, and needed to delete every second file. Find just returned me random files, therefore I added a sort. It now looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
DIRNAME="<directoryNameContainingYourFiles>"
for file in `find $DIRNAME -type f | sort | awk 'NR % 2 == 0'`; do
  echo "going to modify" $file
  #  ls -laFh $file           # show file details
  #  rm $file                 # delete file
  #  mv $file <newDirName>    # move file to <newDirName>
done
```

put this in a file called *scriptName*, run

```
chmod +x scriptName
```

and start it by calling

```
./scriptName
```