# how to reduce number of lines by half with sed

Tags: linux, bash, sed, coordinates

I got a .txt file containing coordinates of points in the format of "x y". They represent a cloud of points on a plane. My idea was to reduce the "density" of the cloud reducing the number of the points by half. I am using linux so to do it i thought to delete half of the lines with sed but just the even or the odd or anyway one line on two. 
To make it clearer i will post an example:

Before

```
435.225 108.891
435.212 108.894 <-- to delete
435.225 108.894
435.238 108.894 <-- to delete
435.3 108.894
435.212 108.897 <-- to delete
435.238 108.897
435.288 108.897 <-- to delete
```

After

```
435.225 108.891
435.225 108.894
435.3 108.894
435.238 108.897
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With `sed`:

```
$ sed -n 1~2p file
435.225 108.891
435.225 108.894
435.3 108.894
435.238 108.897
```

It prints lines whose number is `2K+1`, that is, odd ones.

Or deleting the even ones ([thanks anishane!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19633952/how-to-reduce-number-of-lines-by-half-with-sed/19633994#comment29150640_19633994)):

```
$ sed 2~2d file
435.225 108.891
435.225 108.894
435.3 108.894
435.238 108.897
```

From [`man sed`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?sed):

> Addresses ---> first~step
>
> Match every step'th line starting with line first.  For example, ''sed
>   -n     1~2p''  will  print all the odd-numbered lines in the input stream, and the address 2~5 will match every fifth line, starting with
>   the second. (This is an extension.)

With `awk` is just this:

```
$ awk 'NR%2' file
435.225 108.891
435.225 108.894
435.3 108.894
435.238 108.897
```

As `NR` stands for line number, `NR%2` will be true just on odd ones, so these will be the ones printed.

Comment: +1. I wasn't aware of the `sed` example you have mentioned. could you provide any documentation which will explain the `1~2` behavior. Thanks.

Comment: Sure, @slayedbylucifer, just updated with some references from `man sed`.

Comment: @slayedbylucifer BTW, `~` is a GNU extension so the command might not give expected results on OSX.  The [linked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2560411/how-to-remove-every-other-line-with-sed) question contains more options on how to achieve this.

Comment: `sed -n 1~2p` or `sed 2~2d`...

Comment: @anishsane then you need to print the line, so `sed -n '2~2d;p'` will make it.

Comment: No, don't add `-n`, just `sed 2~2d`. Anyway, your approach & this are _almost_ same.

Comment: Aaah now I see, @anishsane. Just updated my answer with your comment. Thanks. The logic behind them is the same, what is missing to convert  *almost* to *same*? :) I guess yours is more portable as per my `-n`.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you:

```
sed 'n;d' file
```

for odd numbers.

And:

```
sed '1!n;d' file
```

for even.

Answer (score 0):

Try running this logic in script (.sh file)

```
#!/bin/bash
cnt=0
while read line
do


 if [ $cnt -eq 0 ] 
 then 
   echo $line >> output.txt
   cnt=1
 elif [ $cnt -eq 1 ]
  then
    cnt=0
 fi
done < inputfile.txt
```